# "not all arguments converted during string formatting" when setting multiple global variables

Tags: python

I wanted to generate unique variable using iteration. I tried writing a code using globals() function but for some reason its not working.

```
for i in (range(0,7)): 
    for v in range(0,7): 
        globals()['element%s' % (i,v)] = []
```

Comment: You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) directly

Comment: "for some reason its not working" -> Could you be more specific? Do you get an error message or some other indicator of what went wrong?

Comment: Yes. This is the error. 'TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-9d6e287105e1> in <module>
      1 for i in (range(0,7)):
      2     for v in range(0,7):
----> 3         globals()['element%s' % (i,v)] = []
      4 

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You honestly just *shouldn't* play with `globals` ([reading material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)). But your error comes from the fact that the arguments you're trying to turn to a string `(i, v)` have size 2, and there's a single place where you demanded a conversion: the `%s`. If you want it to work there needs to be 2X `%s` in your string:

```
for i in (range(0,4)):
    for v in range(0,3):
        print('%selement%s' % (i,v))
```

```
0element0
0element1
0element2
1element0
1element1
1element2
2element0
2element1
2element2
3element0
3element1
3element2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes with the text formating.

Try `globals()[f'elements{i,v}'] = []` instead.

Comment: It does create the variables but when I call that variable its shows this error: 'name 'elements' is not defined'. I'm looking for output something like element00, element01, element02 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. Note that modifying `globals()` is rarely a good idea, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) instead.

```
for i in range(5):
  globals()['myvar'+str(i)] = i**2

print(myvar2)
print(myvar3)
```

Output:

```
4
9
```